# I Cannot Perform Oauth

Tags: support, api, api-v2, authentication, oauth2

My Clientn id = `4784`
and Key = `cB0l6XiaOW5l5vsBnBeIUg((`.

What do I do for Oauth and to get an access token?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

The authentication process is described in the API docs: http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication.